# xsl declare variable and reassign/change value in for-each is not working

Tags: xslt

I'm declaring variable "flag" in for-each and reassigning value inner for-each. I'm getting error duplicate variable within the scope.

```
My code is:

  <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'0'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="Properties/Property">
          <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'0'"/>
     <xsl:choose>             
                  <xsl:when test="$language='en-CA'">                 
                    <xsl:for-each select="Localization/[Key=$language]">
                      <xsl:value-of select="Value/Value"/>
                      <xsl:variable name="flag" select="'1'"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:if test="$flag ='0'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$flag"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                  </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Can we update/re-assign variable value? If not Do we have any other options? 
    Any help?

Comment: What is this variable used for? What is your intended result here?

Comment: I want to use just like Flag. Depending on flag value I want to display some data.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is not a procedural language and variables in XSLT don't behave like variables in procedural languages; they behave more like variables in mathematics. That is, they are names for values. The formula x=x+1 makes no sense in mathematics and it makes no sense in XSLT either.

It's always difficult to reverse-engineer a specification from procedural code, especially from incorrect procedural code. So tell us what you are trying to achieve, and we will tell you the XSLT way (that is, the declarative/functional way) of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT variables are single-assignment.

Comment: Do we have any other option?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an xsl template and do xsl recursion. 
for example:

```
<xsl:template name="IncrementUntil5">
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="number(1)" />
    <xsl:if test="$counter &lt; 6">
        <test><xsl:value-of select="$counter"/></test>
        <xsl:call-template name="IncrementUntil5">
            <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>        
</xsl:template>
```

then call it like this:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">       
        <div>
            <xsl:call-template name="IncrementUntil5"/>
        </div>    
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Properties/Property">
    <xsl:choose>             
      <xsl:when test="$language='en-CA' and Localization/Key='en-CA'">                 
        <xsl:value-of select="Value/Value"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You don't need to iterate through a collection to determine if something's present, the simple XPath `Localization/Key='en-CA'` will be true if there's any element matching it that exists.